# Translation of Record Name value

Tags: formula, custom-metadata, translation

I have an `Object A` with a lookup field to `Object B` and a `Language__c` field. I would like to create another field on `Object A` to display the record name value of the record from `Object B` in a correct language based on the `Language__c` field.

I was thinking about building a formula where I would define one field (resource) as a combination of other field values.

Example: I have the following formula which retrieves the French translation of the `FieldA` from Custom Metadata Types, if `Language__c='FR'`.

`IF( Language__c  = 'FR', $CustomMetadata.Translation__mdt.FieldA_FR.Translation__c, Field__c)`

What I'm looking for is to simplify this in case I would have multiple languages and many records with `FieldA` to be translated. Something like this:

`$CustomMetadata.Translation__mdt.FieldA_+'Language__c'+.Translation__c`

Then it would simply take the `Language__c` value and finds the right Custom Metadata Type record. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Via a formula - no. This sounds like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - please edit your question and describe what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @identigral thanks for pointing it out, you are correct. I've updated the question with the actual problem.

Comment: Translation of record (field) values in this type of dynamic way requires a custom UI (e.g. custom LWC). You would do much of this work in Apex.